# Delphi (10.2): fast Integer conversion to string with separator

Tags: string, performance, delphi, format

Let's say we have this Integer 1234567890, we want it converted to a string with a separator = 1.234.567.890, we could do Format('%n',[1234567890.0]); but it's very slow. I wrote a function to speed it up considerably (more than 2x faster). How could I improve it further, or can you come up with a faster routine?

```
function MyConvertDecToStrWithDot(Const n: UInt64): string;
Var a,b,x: Integer;
    z,step: Integer;
    l: SmallInt;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(n);
  if n < 1000 then Exit;

  l := Length(Result);
  a := l div 3;
  b := l mod 3;
  step := b+1;

  z := 4;
  if b <> 0 then begin
    Insert('.',Result,step);
    Inc(z,step);
  end;
  for x := 1 to (a-1) do begin
    Insert('.',Result,z);
    Inc(z,4);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var a: Integer;
    s: string;
begin
  PerfTimerInit;
  for a := 1 to 1000000 do
   s := MyConvertDecToStrWithDot(1234567890);
  Memo1.lines.Add(PerfTimerStopMS.ToString);
  caption := s;
end;
```

32-bit

> Format: ~230ms
>   My function: ~79ms

64-bit

> Format: ~440ms
>   My function: ~103ms

Comment: `%n` formats floating point values. That explains why it is slower than your code.

Comment: Your function is unnecessarily slow. You start out converting to string, then increase the length of the string 1 char at a time as you add separators; at each insert shuffling the other characters across. And all this is to replace a flexible `Format` function that supports a variety of features including: decimals; `',' or ' '` as separators; or even no separator with a function that supports only a single inflexible approach to formatting. The point of what I'm saying is: What's the ***point***? What are you trying to achieve? I doubt you have a ***real*** performance problem with `Format`.

Comment: What are you doing that an extra 300 ms converting an integer to a string is the bottleneck you feel needs optimizing in your code?

Comment: **PS**: Your function doesn't even support signed integers. _If you compare apples and oranges, expect different results._ And those comparisons will be meaningless.

Comment: @alcalde An extra 300ms converting an integer to  a string _would_ be a concern. However, OP is converting 1000000 integers. So the question is: "Why is an extra 0.0003ms a considered to be a bottleneck that needs optimising?"

Comment: @Craig/Alcalde the point is I need specifically this conversion, and format is almost 3 times slower. I am processing large amounts of text where this conversion takes place thousands or even millions of times every second. I don't need it to support signed integers.

Comment: It's still doubtful to me whether this is the bottleneck. It's plausible, but have you actually checked? Do you know what is meant by the term bottleneck? If I had to optimise this, I'd make sure that there was only a single heap allocation.

Comment: So that would involve performing the conversion to decimal string into a char array, splicing in separators as you go. Then performing heap allocation. A good DivMod will help. That delphi doesn't have an int to string that can work without heap allocation is very distressing. But if this code isn't a bottleneck, it's a waste of time. Have you timed the real program as well as just the conversion functions?

Comment: @hikari Your justification confuses the issue more: "_processing large amounts of **text**_"? So you start with text, convert to int, then convert back to text, then perform text manipulation to get a specific format? That already sounds a inefficient. Also: "_**or even** millions of times every second_". That still sound like you're not really sure of your actual performance requirement. More importantly; whatever target system expects these integers in a relatively complex format instead of binary cannot be that performant itself. I still don't believe you've profiled your problem properly.

Comment: @David this function is just one of many that I'm trying to optimize for an overall speed improvement

Comment: That's not how you optimise. Find the bottleneck. Optimise that. Repeat until you can't improve further. You are quite likely wasting your time.

Comment: @Craig The processing involves first extracting (converting) those integers from a text source in a multitude of few different formats (1 234 1,234 1.234 and others, within more text) then 1) storing those int values 2) presenting those values with a new formatting.

Comment: What's the point of arguing why I need this or that however? I asked a very a specific question, included a solution and asked for improvements to that very specific task, it's pretty annoying how few people at SO keep doing this on people's questions.

Comment: @hikari Because we like to help people learn. You don't want to learn, it seems. And it is interesting to note that your latest comment shows that your entire approach is poorly thought out. Don't convert from text to integer and then back again. Reformat entirely as text, and possibly avoid heap allocation and `string` completely. That is if this entire thing isn't a waste of time. I have over 20 years experience in performance critical development. I've seen people making the mistake of premature and pointless optimisation so many times.

Comment: It's still faster to do this conversion. I need both the integer value and the formatted display, so I need the initial str to int conversion either way. Calling MyConvertDecToStrWithDot with an Integer Const+IntToStr is still faster than calling MyConvertDecToStrWithDot with a string or even doing a StringReplace during the initial processing (on Tokyo 10.2 at least)

Comment: No it is not. It is faster to work from the original string when formatting.

Comment: Yes it is, "MyConvertDecToStrWithDot(1234567890)" is faster than "StringReplace('1 234 567 890',' ','.',[rfReplaceAll])"

Comment: @hikari if you need both the int value and the string then why don't just write a function that do the int conversion and string formatting at once?

Comment: About the art of [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) : *"Premature optimization" is a phrase used to describe a situation where a programmer lets performance considerations affect the design of a piece of code. This can result in a design that is not as clean as it could have been or code that is incorrect, because the code is complicated by the optimization and the programmer is distracted by optimizing."*

Comment: cont. *"When deciding whether to optimize a specific part of the program, Amdahl's Law should always be considered: the impact on the overall program depends very much on how much time is actually spent in that specific part, which is not always clear from looking at the code without a performance analysis."*

Comment: cont. *"A better approach is therefore to design first, code from the design and then profile/benchmark the resulting code to see which parts should be optimized. A simple and elegant design is often easier to optimize at this stage, and profiling may reveal unexpected performance problems that would not have been addressed by premature optimization.

In practice, it is often necessary to keep performance goals in mind when first designing software, but the programmer balances the goals of design and optimization."*

Comment: @CraigYoung " OP is converting 1000000 integers." In that case, if premature optimization is the root of all evil, we are staring into the binary code of Satan itself!

Comment: No. It really is faster to work directly with the original text.

Comment: @David depends on the format of the original text. "123 456 789 0" -> you need both an Integer and a formatted version with dots, it's faster to remove the spaces+convert to int+convert the int to the dotted format than it is to generate both the Integer and the dotted format from that source string. MyConvertDecToStrWithDot is faster than a StringReplace.

Comment: No, it is faster to work from the text. It's only you that wants to use the immensely inefficient `StringReplace`. I would not do that. I would walk over the string copying digits, and seps, to a fixed length character array. Then I would create a string from that. This avoids excessive heap allocations.

Comment: It's still faster to remove all non-numeric chars and doing both conversions than what you are suggesting.

Comment: No it is not. I don't think you understand this at all well, and I'm quite sure that you don't know what I am suggesting. Never mind. Do it your way.

Comment: then prove me wrong with some code

Comment: You don't need code to appreciate that copying a character to an array is quicker than calling `DivMod`, and then copying a character to an array.

Answer (score 4):

In my tests, the following is ever so slightly faster:

```
function ThousandsSepStringOf(Num: UInt64): string;
const
  MaxChar = 30; // Probably, 26 is enough: 19 digits + 7 separators
var
  Count: Integer;
  Rem: UInt64;
  Res: array[0..MaxChar] of Char;
  WritePtr: PChar;
begin
  WritePtr := @Res[MaxChar];
  WritePtr^ := #0;
  Count := 0;
  while Num > 0 do
  begin
    DivMod(Num, 10, Num, Rem);
    Dec(WritePtr);
    WritePtr^ := Char(Byte(Rem) + Ord('0'));
    Inc(Count);
    if Count = 3 then
    begin
      Dec(WritePtr);
      WritePtr^ := '.';
      Count := 0;
    end;
  end;
  if WritePtr^ = '.' then
    Inc(WritePtr);
  Count := MaxChar - ((NativeInt(WritePtr) - NativeInt(@Res)) shr 1);
  SetLength(Result, Count);
  Move(WritePtr^, PByte(Result)^, Count * SizeOf(Char));
end;
```

Tested with:

```
procedure TestHisCode;
Var
  a: Integer;
  s: string;
  SW: TStopwatch;
begin
  Writeln('His code');
  SW := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for a := 1 to KLoops do
    s := MyConvertDecToStrWithDot(1234567890);
  Writeln(SW.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  Writeln(s);
  Writeln;
end;

procedure TestMyCode;
Var
  a: Integer;
  s: string;
  SW: TStopwatch;
begin
  Writeln('My code');
  SW := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for a := 1 to KLoops do
    s := ThousandsSepStringOf(1234567890);
  Writeln(SW.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  Writeln(s);
  Writeln;
end;
```

and:

```
  TestHisCode;
  TestMyCode;
  TestMyCode;
  TestHisCode;
  TestMyCode;
  TestHisCode;
  TestHisCode;
  TestMyCode;
```

Comment: But I must admit, I hadn't expected that code that uses `IntToStr` and then `Insert` repeatedly would be so performant.

Comment: It's a bit slower on my system, 10000000 iterations: mine averages 800-810ms, yours around 900ms (2500K 4.3 ghz), Tokyo 10.2

Comment: Did you test several times? My test is like: `TestHisCode; TestMyCode; TestMyCode; TestHisCode; TestMyCode; TestHisCode; TestHisCode; TestMyCode;`. And I used TStopwatch, not the non-standard functions you use.

Comment: Same results with TStopWatch, I was using the same with QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter: 
https://pastebin.com/c2ET7F43

Comment: But you did not mix tests, like I did? Anyway, on my system mine is slightly faster.

Comment: Which version of Delphi? here are the project files to test without any extra units: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Kd3pQSz9EkZ1E0eENxeWdSX0U

Comment: @hikari: 10.2 Tokyo. Windows 7 in Parallels on a 2010 Mac (CPU 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7). Optimization on.

Comment: FWIW, I got (using TStopwatch): `Memo1
My proc: 1273ms
My proc: 1275ms
My proc: 1261ms
Other procs: 1248ms
Other procs: 1349ms
Other procs: 1316ms
Other procs: 1294ms
Other procs: 1283ms
Other procs: 1249ms
Other procs: 1333ms
Other procs: 1249ms
Other procs: 1349ms
My proc: 1252ms
My proc: 1356ms
My proc: 1298ms
My proc: 1239ms
My proc: 1351ms`.

Comment: That's odd. I tried in a W7 VM: http://i.imgur.com/IPmOyOt.png then normal pc on W10: http://i.imgur.com/35ndAwq.png

Comment: Well, sorry, not here. Perhaps your PCs have newer processors that behave differently.

Comment: Could be, idk. I have a Sandy Bridge i5-2500k from 2011

Comment: More than the CPU I'd say it's probably related to Parallels/mac

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "_But I must admit, I hadn't expected that code that uses `IntToStr` and then `Insert` repeatedly would be so performant._" In some cases FastMem (depending on the specific size partition boundaries involved) will hide some of the performance problems of repeated `Insert` by avoiding realloc. Character shuffling remains in play though. So I expect hikari's function would suffer more with 20 digit numbers. That said I suspect there is one possibly significant improvement to consider in your function...

Comment: ... The line `WritePtr^ := Char(Byte(Rem) + Ord('0'));` converts a Byte to a Char on each iteration. It may be more efficient to simply lookup `WritePtr^ := Digits[Rem];` for an appropriately defined `Digits` constant.

Comment: @craig arithmetic ought to be faster, Rudy's version should beat lookup

Comment: @Rudy Variants with heap allocation won't shine under multiple threads, your version will.

Comment: @hikari: No, certainly not Parallels. It uses the full power of the CPU, even if it is pretty old.

Comment: @Craig: I don't think so. See what David wrote.

Comment: You ignore 0 input. Also Im not sure if this code intended to work with older versions such D7. But I get wrong length for the reault string. eg for input 1 the length is 16

Answer (score 0):

Haven't properly tested the performance of this, however it should be cross-platform and locale independent:

```
function Thousands(const ASource: string): string;
var
  I, LLast: Integer;
begin
  Result := ASource;
  LLast := Length(Result);
  I := LLast;
  while I > 0 do
  begin
    if (LLast - I + 1) mod 3 = 0 then
    begin
      Insert(FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator, Result, I);
      Dec(I, 2);
    end
    else
      Dec(I);
  end;
end;
```

Note: It obviously just works on integers

Comment: it's still a little bit locale dependent. Because not every locale puts the separator every 3 digits. For example [Indians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) will write 1234567890123 as `12,34,56,78,90,123` whereas CJK languages may write it as `1,2345,6789,0123`

Comment: This approach is around 62% slower than mine (adding IntToStr since we are calling with an Integer). FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator also adds a lot of processing: with it: 200ms, with '.' = 130ms. (vs 79ms from mine)

Comment: edit: actually just 8-9ms slower by changing ASource to an Integer and calling IntToStr from within the function.

Comment: @hikari My initial tests didn't show it anywhere near that slow. Something less than 10ms. I'll revisit it later

Comment: 10000000 iterations: ~810ms my proc, ~870ms yours

Answer (score -2):

It's better to insert the separators directly *while constructing the string* instead of inserting separators later into the converted string because each insertion involves a lot of data movements and performance degradation. Besides avoid the division by 3 may improve performance a bit

This is what I get from my rusty Pascal after decades not using it

```
uses strutils;

function FormatNumber(n: integer): string;
var digit: integer;
    count: integer;
    isNegative: boolean;
begin
    isNegative := (n < 0);
    if isNegative then n := -n;
    Result := '';
    count  := 3;

    while n <> 0 do begin
        digit := n mod 10;
        n     := n div 10;

        if count = 0 then begin
            Result := Result + '.';
            count  := 3;
        end;
        Result := Result + chr(ord('0') + digit);
        dec(count);
    end;

    if isNegative then Result := Result + '-';
    Result := reversestring(Result);
end;
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/6O3e8w

It's also faster to just assign the characters directly instead of using concatenation operator/function like Victoria suggested. This is the improved version with only unsigned types

```
type string28 = string[28];

function FormatNumber(n: UInt64): string28;
var digit: integer;
    length: integer;
    count: integer;
    c: char;
begin
    count  := 3;
    length := 0;

    while n <> 0 do begin
        digit := n mod 10;
        n     := n div 10;

        if count = 0 then begin
            inc(length);
            Result[length] := '.';
            count  := 3;
        end;

        inc(length);
        Result[length] := chr(ord('0') + digit);
        dec(count);
    end;

    for count := 1 to (length + 1) div 2 do begin
        c := Result[count];
        Result[count] := Result[length - count + 1];
        Result[length - count + 1] := c;
    end;
    setlength(Result, length);

    FormatNumber := Result;
end;
```

If the operation is done millions of times and is really a bottleneck after profiling, it's better to do in multiple threads along with [SIMD](https://github.com/WojciechMula/simd-string)

Comment: Concatenation also involves performance degradation. Just allocate the string length in forward.

Comment: @Victoria yes, but I'm not sure how to do it in Delphi. Anyway as from what I've just read `string` will always be allocated as 256 bytes in Delphi

Comment: This one is very slow: mine 804ms vs 3700ms (10000000 iterations)

Comment: @hikari as I said I'm not proficient in Delphi so I'm not sure what to use to optimize some operations. Anyway it seems that there's some problem with your benchmark. Microbenchmark is not easy. Did you even use optimizations when compiling?

Comment: Of course optimization is On. I use QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter to benchmark